# How to configure nats.io with TSL connection for python3 properly?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ssl, docker-compose, nats.io

I'm trying to configure `nats.io` server with `tls` support.

Done so far:

- [ SSL ] Created automated TLS cert generation script. Basically it uses `openssl` to generate ca key/cert pair, and then if pair is generated creates "descendant" certificates. Everything happens proper way with creating key, then generating csr request and signing client cert with CA key. Long story short **no problem here**.
- [ DOCKER ] Created `docker-compose.yml` for nats container. It looks like this and pretty much runs OK. The question is: **do I have to specify `nats server` name through `-c` command**?

```yaml
    version: "3.5"
    
    services:
      nats:
        image: nats
        container_name: nats
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: "--cluster_name natscluster --name nats -c /etc/nats/pm-nats.conf"
        expose:
          - "4222"
        ports:
          - "4222:4222"
          - "8222:8222"
          - "6222:6222"
        networks:
          - natscluster
        volumes:
          - ./ssl/server.pem:/certs/server.pem:ro
          - ./ssl/server-key.pem:/certs/server-key.pem:ro
          - ./ssl/ca.pem:/certs/ca.pem:ro
          - ./ssl/route.pem:/certs/route.pem:ro
          - ./ssl/route-key.pem:/certs/route-key.pem:ro
          - ./config/pm-nats.conf:/etc/nats/pm-nats.conf
    
    networks:
      natscluster:
        name: natscluster
        driver: bridge
```

- [ NATS ] nats server config. This is kinda hard part. I couldn't find one solid TLS enabled config. But found several different kinds of config file syntax.
  For example: official docs define `listen: <ip:port>` directive, although in lots of examples there is just `port:<port number>` specified.
  Also there are notations with

```yaml
      tls {
        cert_file = '/certs/route.pem'
      }
```

as well as

```yaml
      tls: {
        cert_file: '/certs/route.pem'
      }
```

would be good to have one reference config with proper syntax to lean on.

My current config is:

```yaml
    port: 4222
    
    https_port: 8222
    tls {
      cert_file = '/certs/server.pem'
      key_file = '/certs/server-key.pem'
      ca_file = '/certs/ca.pem'
      verify = true
      timeout = 2
    }
    
    cluster {
      name: "natscluster"
      port: 6222
      tls {
        cert_file = '/certs/route.pem'
        key_file = '/certs/route-key.pem'
        ca_file = '/certs/ca.pem'
        timeout = 5
      }
    
      authorization {
        user: my_user
        password: my_password
        timeout: 2
      }
    
      routes = []
    }
```

- [ PYTHON ] To connect I use `nats-py` package. Am I correct to generate client key/cert pair signed with same CA as generated for server above and use this TLS keys to connect server?
  Upon connection `docker logs nats` gives me the following line:

```sh
[ERR] 192.168.88.10:14433 - cid:6 - "v2.0.0:python3" - processSub Parse Error: 'test <function message_handler at 0x0000001111111110> 1'
```

testing it with (tried using both client and server certificate/key pairs).

```sh
/usr/local/bin/nats sub --tlsca=./script/../ssl/ca.pem --tlscert=./script/../ssl/client.pem --tlskey=./script/../ssl/client-key.pem -s tls://127.0.0.1:4222
```

returns to console:

```sh
nats: error: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs, try --help
```

tried help, but got no help :( sadly `--trace`, `--raw` and `--dump` keys haven't shed light on this issue.

server logs give me:

```sh
[ERR] 172.19.0.1:42940 - cid:6 - TLS handshake error: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

I do understand that certificate is bad, but can't understand in which way.

Would be grateful for any help. 
Regards.

Comment: Starting to answer my own question:
This connections should be made with container name which is specified in certificate CN. I tried to connect from localhost and this spoiled everything.
`/usr/local/bin/nats sub --tlsca=./script/../ssl/ca.pem --tlscert=./script/../ssl/client.pem --tlskey=./script/../ssl/client-key.pem -s tls://mq:4222
`

This leaves me with another problem: how to connect from outside of docker host?

Comment: OK, connection issues pretty much resolved by using reference TLS call from here: https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py
Making class of it is still in progress.
Quesion with config syntax still stands.

Comment: The feeling when you stumble upon your own answer...